# Can I store an iterator in a file which I can read from later? Will this reduce space consumption?

Tags: python, file, compression, iterable

Let's say I have a very large integer, around the order of 10**200. Now storing the integer in a file will take some amount of space.

If I convert it into an iterator using `yield`, can I store the iterator in a file instead? 
Will this save any resources?

The iterator can be generated like this:

```
def rec():
  for i in range(0,10**200):
    yield i

iterable = rec()
```

Comment: `10**200` has 201 decimal digits. How does storing that require a "large amount of space?"

Comment: okay i meant will storing the iterable save space or resources. Edited the question.

Comment: What do you mean by converting it into an iterable using `yield`?

Comment: What problem are actually you trying to solve here? Do you have some code that's running too slowly, or using too much memory, or creating a file that is too large?

Comment: trying to compress a large integer matrix.

Comment: @ritratt Why don't you start with what you are trying to compress, and what you have tried.

Comment: @ritratt: you should read up on the XY problem: [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I will have to create a new question for that. In short, I am compressing a large string by converting it into an array of integers. Problem is, the integers themselves are longer than the string.

Comment: @ritratt you should delete this question then.

Comment: Ok i have fallen into the XY trap. I guess this was a bad question. Will create a more detailed one if shelving/pickling is not the answer!

Comment: @ritratt: you should really read about basic information theory. In particular about [Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29), [Kolgomorov Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on [larsmans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13220540/257111) answer, a custom iterator can be built to do this:

```
class my_large_num(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.num_iterations = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self


    def next(self):
        if self.num_iterations < 1:
            self.num_iterations += 1
            return 10**200
        else:
            raise StopIteration()
```

You can then:

```
import pickle
pickled_repr = pickle.dumps(my_large_num())
restored_object = pickle.loads(pickled_repr)
sum(restored_object)
```

This works because underneath, iterable objects have a `next()` function which raises `StopIteration` when done. All we're doing is creating a class that implements this functionality.

In this specific case, regardless of the fact you have stored the class in a file, you still need to perform the iteration, and thus store `10**200` in memory, so you gain no functionality except generating the number on demand, which you can do without serializing the object.

You might be thinking of [mmap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) style space saving. This maps memory to a file - note however this still affects the usable memory of your program.

Comment: This works. It is also using lesser amount of space on the disk. However, as you mentioned, the number 10**200 will still have to be loaded into the memory during runtime so no saving there. Thanks a lot.
What I am wondering now is why we dont use this method to store most of the large integers already?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is what you'd like to do:

```
def f():
    yield 10**200
```

Then save `f()` in a file. The answer is no, that won't work. An generator like `f()` (note: that's generator, not iterable) cannot be pickled or otherwise serialized unless you turn it into a custom iterator with special-purpose pickling support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Shelve`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) Module to store this.

> A “shelf” is a persistent, dictionary-like object. The difference with
>   “dbm” databases is that the values (not the keys!) in a shelf can be
>   essentially arbitrary Python objects — anything that the pickle module
>   can handle.

[The following types can be pickled](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)

Comment: Why do I need a link to `itertools.chain`?

Comment: Ok this looks promising. Reading up now. I wonder if this uses lesser amount of resources.

Comment: @ritratt you can save even more resources if you use `xrange()` instead of `range()`, as `range()` creates the whole list first and `xrange()` returns an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

An integer of the value 10**200 does not take a large amount of space. Encoded in base 10 ASCII, that takes only 201 characters. If you're willing to store your data in binary, then you're looking at only 85ish

---

If you mean "iterable", that doesn't make much sense either - an iterable is essentially a function, and you already have the function saved - *it's in the source file*.

Comment: okay i meant will storing the iterable save space. Edited the question.

Comment: @ritratt: Did you? Looks the same to me.

Comment: An iterable is an object, not a function.